# Java - removing specific characters from text in jeditorpane

Tags: java, arrays, string, jeditorpane

I would appreciate some help modifying a function!

The aims:
Make an array list of specific characters.
Write a method to remove the characters specified in the arraylist from text JEditorpane.

So Far:
Made an arraylist of characters,
Wrote a function to remove the characters.
made a gui that includes jeditorpane

The issue:
The function works, and remove characters that I println to console via a string.

I am struggling to make the function remove the characters from the text document that i open into JEditorpane.

The code in short:

```
     private static ArrayList<Character> special = new  ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('a','b','h'));



    public class removing implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

documentpane is the name of my jeditorpane

if I change, document.chatAt, to test.chatAt, (which is printing to console, this works.

```
        Document document = documentpane.getDocument();

        String test = "hello world?";
        String outputText = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < document.getLength(); i++) {
            Character c = new Character(document.charAt(i));
            if (!special.contains(c))
                outputText += c;
            else
                outputText += " ";
        }
        System.out.println(outputText);
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `Document` doesn't have a `charAt` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Document` doesn't have `charAt` method you first need to extract the content of the document. This can be done by the following:

```
String content = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
```

Then when using your `for-loop` with `content` it should work. So your code would look like this:

```
Document document = documentpane.getDocument();
String content = document.getText(0, document.getLength());
String outputText = "";
for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
    Character c = new Character(content.charAt(i));
    if (!special.contains(c))
       outputText += c;
    else
       outputText += " ";
}
System.out.println(outputText);
```

Comment: Hi Lino, Thanks for the reply,

I have implemented your solution, just having one error.
 
for (int i = 0; i < content.getLength(); i++) {

content.getLength() is having a warning, just stating the method is undefined for the type of string. Change to length(..). 

Any more input?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry had to edit the commend when you replied! see above!

Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, typo of me `length()` is what i meant

Comment: yea, I figured it out and surrounded with try catch, thanks again for the update.

Comment: Last thing on this matter, 

This is removing the characters, and pasting the what is in the JEdiorpane to the console with characters deleted. (almost perfect), how can I modify this to update the text that is in the JEditorpane?

Thanks!!

Comment: @Shane try `documentPane.setText(outputText)` after the loop

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Shane glad i could help you. Also accept this answer, so it is closed, because your problem is solved and it isnt listed as unanswered

Answer (score -2):

How about this :

```
    String outputText =document.getText(0,docuemnt.getLength()).replaceAll("[a|b|c]"," ");
   //set regex that you want 
    System.out.println(outputText);
```

You can use document.getText(0,docuemnt.getLength()) As lino suggested. But I prefer regex cause you do not have to loop and check, Using StringBuilder instead of concatenation is a better practice